# How to use firebase cloud functions minInstances

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a number of firebase cloud functions. I try to set 1 of them to warm like this:

```
export const regionalFunctions = functions.region(cloudFunctionRegion);
export const manageDocs = regionalFunctions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 9 * 60, memory: '256MB' as '256MB', minInstances: 1 }).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
```

but when I try to deploy the code it looks like it sets minInstances to 1 for all my cloud functions. Output from firebase deploy:

```
functions: The following functions have reserved minimum instances. This will reduce the frequency of cold starts but increases the minimum cost. You will be charged for the memory allocation and a fraction of the CPU allocation of instances while they are idle.

addFromCloudService(europe-west1): 1 instances, 256MB of memory each
mailChimp(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
manageDocs(europe-west1): 1 instances, 256MB of memory each
onCreate(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
onDocumentCreate(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
onDocumentDelete(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
onFinalize(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
onUserAdded(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
onUserDelete(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
paddleUpgrade(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
paddleWebhook(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each
splitDocument(europe-west1): 1 instances, 2GB of memory each

With these options, your minimum bill will be $194.12 in a 30-day month
? Would you like to proceed with deployment? No
```

Why is it doing this, when I have only set minInstances for the function manageDocs? How can I set minInstances for only 1 function?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you show us all of the code and steps that anyone can use to reproduce this?  Right now you're just showing one function, but we need to see all of the code, in addition to the way you use the CLI to deploy them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same :)

It happens because each `.runWith` is linked to the same constant (`regionalFunctions` in your case)

so if we remove `regionalFunctions` constant and call each function via new `functions.region(cloudFunctionRegion).runWith`, everything should be fine